# Dealing with special characters when creating commands to eval

Tags: vimscript

I'm writing some functions to make it easier to manage vim's current directory and I'm trying to figure out how to quote the directory name when assembling a command to execute.

Basically, I'm running `execute printf("chdir %s", expand("%:h"))` and I'd like to know how to make it more secure/predictable/functionally correct.

I can make that snippet a little bit more robust by using `'` like this:

```
execute printf("chdir '%s'", expand("%:h"))
```

But I'm wondering if there's a solution that handles all cases.

For some context/motivation,

I have `noautochdir` set and a global variable `g:dir_jump_orig` to the value of the current working directory on startup:

```
set noautochdir
let g:dir_jump_orig = $PWD

function! DirJumpGoFocused()
  execute printf("chdir %s", expand("%:h"))
endfunction

function! DirJumpGoOrig()
  execute printf("chdir %s", g:dir_jump_orig))
endfunction

nnoremap <leader><c-i> :<c-u>call DirJumpGoOrig()<CR>
nnoremap <leader>c     :<c-u>call DirJumpGoFocused()<CR>
```

I'd like to make `DirJumpGoOrig` and `DirJumpGoFocused` more reliable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for `fnameescape()`:

```
execute 'cd ' . fnameescape(expand("%:h"))
```

For more help see `:h fnameescape()`.